# Terraform Azuread_Group membership

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Need some suggestions in working with Terraform azuread_group

## My group.json:

```
[
{
    "team_name": "Test Group1",
    "members": [
        "c817f52a-1234-4bf2-b342-5424c7ed8ec7",
        "41394961-1234-4169-97a4-55fdaf208680"
    ]
},
{
    "team_name": "Test Group2",
    "members": [
        "c817f52a-f997-4bf2-b342-5424c7ed8ec7",
        "41394961-e12c-4169-97a4-55fdaf208680"
    ]
}
```

]

## My TF:

Below is my TF code to create the AD group.  However, I am not sure how I can create add the members to the group.

```
locals {
    team_name_list = jsondecode(file("${path.module}/group.json"))
}

resource "azuread_group" "provision-aad-group" {
  count = length(local.team_name_list)

  display_name              = local.team_name_list[count.index].team_name
  prevent_duplicate_names   = true
  members = [
    # WHAT TO DO HERE?
  ]
}
```

Any suggestions is appreciated.

Thaks

Answer (score 0):

...update.  Fixed

members = var.aad_group_display_name[count.index].members